# Ontotext GraphDB on Docker - how to work with file on host file system instead of inside the container

Tags: docker, filesystems, host, graphdb

I have Ontotext GraphDb running in a Docker container in Windows Home. I want to create repositories, generate logs and any other operational files in my host file system (Windows), so I can access and work with them from outside the Docker container.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expose the docker ports when you start it - docker run -p 7200:7200....
Then you should be able to connect to http://localhost:7200 on your windows machine.